# Get back to master view programmaticcally - StoryBoard - iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using standard `UISplitViewController`, but for iPhone devices I need get back from detail view to master view programmatically.
Pushing back via the navigation stack does not work since detail view controller and master view controller do have separated navigation controllers.

Is there any chance to accomplish that?

Comment: Provide more detailed information and verify my edit.

Comment: @MarekR yes, standard split view in iOS = UISplitViewController. Sorry there is no more info. The case is simple, solution not.

Comment: Did you tried: [- dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)?

Comment: "Dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by the receiver." My case is push, not modal.

Comment: Are you trying to navigate between master / detail view controllers in split view controller OR navigate in one of the navigation controllers existing in master or detail view controller (push / pop) from other view controller?

Comment: @ArturOlszak UISplitViewController has alway different navigation controllers for master and detail, so this could work only on iPhone devices, except iPhone 6plus landscape

Comment: @Vanya: You did not answer my question. BTW split view controller can have different view controllers assigned to master / detail (not only navigation controllers).

Comment: Sorry @ArturOlszak , I thought I made myself clear when I said "standard" I mean the way it is done when you get a new project from template "Master Detail application" and I did bit describe in the question. BTW: I don't understand your question.